# Express: can I use multiple middleware in a single app.use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a lot of apps full of boilerplate code that looks like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('express-session')({
        secret: 'keyboard cat',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

How can I use multiple middleware at once? So I could turn the above into:

```
// Some file, exporting something that can be used by app.use, that runs multiple middlewares
const bodyParsers = require('body-parsers.js')
const sessions= require('sessions.js')

// Load all bodyparsers
app.use(bodyParsers)

// Load cookies and sessions
app.use(sessions)
```

Comment: Maybe I do not understand a question but you can put all that int boilerplate code for e.g. bodyParser and session into separate files,  and run it main app.js as you have just described...

Comment: Yes, I'd like to put them into separate files, that's what I;m asking about,. I don't know the what that separate file would export, or how to invoke what the separate file exports with `app.use`

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain why?

Comment: In general you don't want to register body parsing like `bodyParser.json()` or `bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })` globally, but individually for each route or group of routes that needs it. e.g. `app.post('/something', bodyParser.json(), (req, res) => {})`. Otherwise you might run into problems if you later need to use different body parsers.

Comment: t.niese Understood. In this case all routes need bodyparsing and cookies.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can specify multiple middlewares, see [the app.use docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use):

> An array of combinations of any of the above.

You can create a file of all middlewares like -

**middlewares.js**

```
module.exports = [
  function(req, res, next){...},
  function(req, res, next){...},
  function(req, res, next){...},
  .
  .
  .
  function(req, res, next){...},
]
```

and as then simply add it like:

```
/*
you can pass any of the below inside app.use()
A middleware function.
A series of middleware functions (separated by commas).
An array of middleware functions.
A combination of all of the above.
*/
app.use(require('./middlewares.js'));
```

Note - Do this only for those middlewares which will be common for all requests

Comment: Exporting an array is definitely a better solution then an object on which `Object.values` is called, because for an array the order in which the middlewares are executed is defined, for `Object.values` it can be any order (it will most likely be consistent throughout one node version, but might change between different node versions)

Comment: @t.niese well pointed!

Answer (score 7):

I like to use a [`Router`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) to encapsulate application routes. I prefer them over a list of routes because a `Router` is like a mini express application.

You can create a `body-parsers` router like so:

```
const {Router} = require('express');

const router = Router();

router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
router.use(cookieParser());
router.use(require('express-session')({
        secret: 'keyboard cat',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
}));
router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());

module.exports = router;
```

Then attach it to your main application like any other route:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(require('./body-parsers'));
```

Comment: Hrm I never considered this - I've run routers for multiple routes, but didn't realise it works for adding regular middleware too.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, in main app.js run just init code:

```
const bodyParserInit = require('./bodyParserInit');
....
bodyParserInit(app);
```

And then in bodyParserInit you can do app.use

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
}
```

Comment: This works, but the existing answer (using `app.use()`) is more idiomatic and better matches the question.