# Is it possible to use multiple middleware functions for just one express endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Basically, is it possible to write code like this with two middleware functions (authenticateToken and authenticateAdminKey) ?

```
app.post('/api', authenticateToken, authenticateAdminKey, function() {
 ...
}
```

I know something similar is possible when you're using multiple middleware for all the endpoints  (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540548/express-can-i-use-multiple-middleware-in-a-single-app-use)). But I wanted to know if something like this is possible for just **one** endpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

middleware list pass in array

```
app.post('/api', [authenticateToken, authenticateAdminKey], function() {
 ...
}
```